# Resilient Gluster mount

Tags: linux, glusterfs

According to https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Setting%20Up%20Clients/#mounting-volumes

> The server specified in the mount command is only used to fetch the gluster configuration volfile describing the volume name. Subsequently, the client will communicate directly with the servers mentioned in the volfile (which might not even include the one used for mount).

when you try to mount to a gluster volume, the first step is to connect to a gluster server to get the configuration volfile.

What happens if that first server is down and THIS initial connect fails (even though SOME OF the other servers are up and THERE IS QUORUM)? The connection should fail, isn't it?

Can I workaround that SINGLE POINT OF FAILURE using several IPs to a single DNS name?

For instance, these are the servers:

```
10.0.0.1 gfs1.example.com
10.0.0.2 gfs2.example.com
10.0.0.3 gfs3.example.com
```

and then on the "example.com" DNS zone:

```
gluster.example.com    A    10.0.0.1 
gluster.example.com    A    10.0.0.2
gluster.example.com    A    10.0.0.3
```

Can I use this command to do the mount?

```
mount -t glusterfs gluster.example.com:/test-volume /mnt/glusterfs
```

Will the mount operation retry the connection attempt with some other IP if the randomly selected one fails?

Will it try every IP on the list until it find some server reachable?

I know most software when there are several IPs to a name, they just select one and use that one, so the above config SHOULD NOT WORK -unless mount.glusterfs have this behavior wired in- which is kind of the question: does it?

In the likely case it doesn’t: is there any way to make this work (some servers down, there is quorum and client trying to connect to the gluster cluster WITH THE SAME ***NAME*** ALWAYS -so, no manual intervention-)?

Comment: "the only winning move is not to play" DNS round robin was not ever meant as a high availability configuration e.g. it does not work well.

Comment: OK, then HOW can I do it? if the initial server is down, how can I do it automatically? Making the user manually change the server name and remount is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Option backupvolfile-server=server name - name of the backup volfile server to mount the client. If this option is added while mounting fuse client, when the first volfile server fails, then the server specified in backupvolfile-server option is used as volfile server to mount the client.

A fstab entry like:

```
gluster01:/volname /mnt/gluster glusterfs defaults,_netdev,backupvolfile-server=gluster02 0 0
```

Do not put several ip addresses of different servers for the same hostname and use it as a gluster node.